# Error importing Biguery to anaconda jupyter notebook

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter

i am trying to import a python package but I keep on getting an error;

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

the error being depicted after running is as seen below;

> `ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 #importing the python package
> ----> 2 from google.cloud import bigquery

ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

`
what could be the reason behind it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, please do

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

Make sure you use same python env in which you run your notebook. Or else you can run

```
! pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

in your notebook before importing.

Comment: should i be doing it in the anaconda prompt? Bcause i am doing it in the anaconda prompt and i keep on getting an error

Comment: try in the jupyter notebook only. ! runs the command like it was written on command line.